# Can you convert a video to an audio file in python without saving to a file?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

For a python web project I receive a video file through a flask interface.
Now to do analysis, I need to extract the audio file from it.

Problem is that I can't save the video to file first, which seemingly eliminates using ffmpeg as it requires a link to a file location.

Are there any python solutions that would allow me to pass and return audio/video files using objects only?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Nobody is answering so I will try to help you, but I did not succeed to make it.

It surely because I do not have compiled myself ffmpeg and so do not have expected codecs .. But anyway, I think what following can help.

Here is a simple Flask server expecting POST query with file and pass it through ffmpeg (using `ffmpy`) without saving it.

```
import os
import subprocess

from ffmpy import FFmpeg

from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)

        stream_file = request.files['file']

        ff = FFmpeg(
            inputs={'pipe:0': 'ARGUMENTS'},
            outputs={'pipe:1': 'ARGUMENTS'}
        )
        stdout, stderr = ff.run(input_data=stream_file.read(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <p><input type=file name=file>
         <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''

app.run()
```

Obviously you have to update `ARGUMENTS` by expected ffmpeg arguments.

Some docs: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#pipe, http://ffmpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#using-pipe-protocol

Comment: I want to execute `ffmpeg -i v1.mp4 v1.m4v` . How can I do this using your method